# One column taller bootstrap (or CSS in general)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

Is below layout possible in bootstrap row and column (or in CSS in general?) - The id of column would have to stay in that order for mobile view.

```
[1][2]
[3][2]
   [2]
   [2]
   [2]


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">Block 1 - sidebar</div>
  <div class="col-md-9">Block 2 - will be long - main content </div>

</div>


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-3">Block 3 - will continue as a sidebar.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might be easier to separate the sidebar from content.

Comment: Even separating, rows will stay one beneath each other?

Answer (score 1):

I would have something like this:

```
[Sidebar][Main]
```

And the Sidebar as:

```
[1]
[3]
```

So the final result would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class"main col-md-3">
                 Sidebar 1
            </div>
            <div class"main col-md-9">
                 Sidebar 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class"main col-md-9">
    Main
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will result in 1,3,2 in mobile view, whilst my intention is to have 1,2,3, providing the 2 is very long, so the 3 will wrap around it from left and stay directly under 1.

Comment: A way you could go around this is to have a cloned [3] which will stay underneath the [2] and it will be hidden-sm and up (only visible on xs)... On the other hand the first [3] will be hidden-xs.

Comment: Or just taking it out of the flow of the page by positioning absolutely?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that also, but then you have to calculate the height for the [1] and [2] containers, and put it bellow it, kinda...